# ASP.NET Core exception processing the key element

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have two machines running the same .NET 7 web project in development. The project is using .NET data protection and both machines have the same configurations in the project. I copied the key-files (xml) from one machine to the other so that they are the same. However, one of the machines throws an exception while using the key-file.

From the trace:

```
trce: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector[5]
      Performing unprotect operation to key {[REMOVED]} with purposes ('[REMOVED]', '[REMOVED]').
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.TypeForwardingActivator[0]
      Forwarded activator type request from Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlDecryptor, Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60 to Microsoft.
AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlDecryptor, Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60
dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlDecryptor[51]
      Decrypting secret element using Windows DPAPI.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlDecryptor[43]
      An exception occurred while trying to decrypt the element.
      System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.UnprotectWithDpapiCore(Byte* pbProtectedData, UInt32 cbProtectedData, Byte* pbOptionalEntropy, UInt32 cbOptionalEntropy)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.UnprotectWithDpapi(Byte[] protectedSecret)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlDecryptor.Decrypt(XElement encryptedElement)
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[24]
      An exception occurred while processing the key element '<key id="[REMOVED]" version="1" />'.
      System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.UnprotectWithDpapiCore(Byte* pbProtectedData, UInt32 cbProtectedData, Byte* pbOptionalEntropy, UInt32 cbOptionalEntropy)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.UnprotectWithDpapi(Byte[] protectedSecret)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlDecryptor.Decrypt(XElement encryptedElement)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.XmlEncryptionExtensions.DecryptElement(XElement element, IActivator activator)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.IInternalXmlKeyManager.DeserializeDescriptorFromKeyElement(XElement keyElement)
trce: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[25]
      An exception occurred while processing the key element '<key id="[REMOVED]" version="1">
        <creationDate>2022-09-15T01:32:44.1371668Z</creationDate>
        <activationDate>2022-09-15T01:32:44.1270795Z</activationDate>
        <expirationDate>2022-12-14T01:32:44.1270795Z</expirationDate>
        <descriptor deserializerType="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AuthenticatedEncryption.ConfigurationModel.AuthenticatedEncryptorDescriptorDeserializer, Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neut
ral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60">
          <descriptor>
            <encryption algorithm="AES_256_CBC" />
            <validation algorithm="HMACSHA256" />
            <encryptedSecret decryptorType="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlDecryptor, Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60" xmlns="http:
//schemas.asp.net/2015/03/dataProtection">
              <encryptedKey xmlns="">
                <!-- This key is encrypted with Windows DPAPI. -->
                <value>[REMOVED]</value>
              </encryptedKey>
            </encryptedSecret>
          </descriptor>
        </descriptor>
      </key>'.
      System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.UnprotectWithDpapiCore(Byte* pbProtectedData, UInt32 cbProtectedData, Byte* pbOptionalEntropy, UInt32 cbOptionalEntropy)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Cng.DpapiSecretSerializerHelper.UnprotectWithDpapi(Byte[] protectedSecret)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.DpapiXmlDecryptor.Decrypt(XElement encryptedElement)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.XmlEncryption.XmlEncryptionExtensions.DecryptElement(XElement element, IActivator activator)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager.Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.Internal.IInternalXmlKeyManager.DeserializeDescriptorFromKeyElement(XElement keyElement)
```

I can see from the trace, that the content of the key-file is exactly the same that is on the machine that works without exception.

So the question is, what can be the reason that one of the machines gets an exception?

Comment: seems like DPAPI would be unique per machine.  (You can't use that on 2 machines...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open the xml files under the directory of

```
C:\Users\SomeUser\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys
```

You could  find  the description :

> This key is encrypted with Windows DPAPI

[image]

Your stacktrace also indicated it

Then let us check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-use-data-protection)

> .NET provides access to the data protection API (DPAPI), which allows
> you to encrypt data using information from the current user account or
> computer.

Since the encryption of the key was based on one of your computer/account,when you copy the xml file to another  and decrypt it , you would get the error as expected

You could  configure as below to specific  how to protect the key:

```
builder.Services.AddDataProtection().ProtectKeysWithCertificate("");
```

check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-6.0#protectkeyswith) for more details